# Tricky SQL Server grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for some help with this tricky SQL query grouping.

I have below set of data. I am looking to find time difference of first (in1=1 & inputs=9) row and first in1=0 row, then next  (in1=1 & inputs=9) and next in1=0 and so on. Please note that I have multiple set of V_Id and within that I have multiple groups of (in1=1 & inputs=9) & in1=0.

Basically I want to find the time difference of two row for each group within V_Id group where the value is changing from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1. I want to add up time difference of multiple sections for each V_Id. Desire output is attached.

I hope my explanation make sense.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you googled Island and gaps problem SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t table(v_id int, _time datetime, inputs tinyint, in1 bit);

insert into @t(v_id, _time, inputs, in1)
values
(1243, '20210114 09:59:50', 0, 0), (1243, '20210114 09:59:58', 0, 0),
(1243, '20210114 10:00:00', 9, 1), (1243, '20210114 10:00:10', 9, 1), (1243, '20210114 10:00:20', 9, 1),
(1243, '20210114 10:00:21', 1, 0), (1243, '20210114 10:00:22', 1, 0), (1243, '20210114 10:00:25', 1, 0),
(1243, '20210114 10:00:27', 9, 1), (1243, '20210114 10:00:28', 9, 1), (1243, '20210114 10:00:29', 9, 1),
(1243, '20210114 10:00:30', 1, 0),
(1243, '20210114 10:00:31', 9, 1), (1243, '20210114 10:00:34', 9, 1), (1243, '20210114 10:00:37', 9, 1) --no following out yet
--,(1243, '20210114 10:00:40', 1, 0)
;

select v_id, sum(secdiff) as sumsecdiff
from
(
    select v_id, grpid, datediff(second, min(starttime), max(endtime)) as secdiff
    from
    (
        select *,
            --groupid
            row_number() over(partition by v_id order by _time) 
            -
            row_number() over(partition by v_id, inputs, in1 order by _time)
            as grpid,
            --starttime of group if previous is out
            case when lag(in1, 1, 0/*in1*/) over(partition by v_id order by _time) = 0 and inputs = 9 and in1 = 1 then _time end as starttime,
            ----endtime of group is the following/next out (if any)
            --case when lead(in1, 1, 1) over(partition by v_id order by _time) = 0 and inputs = 9 and in1 = 1 then lead(_time) over(partition by v_id order by _time) end as endtime

            --endtime of group is the following/next out, if last row is in1=1 (and 9) then getdate() /*it*/ accounts as out
            case when lead(in1, 1, 0) over(partition by v_id order by _time) = 0 and inputs = 9 and in1 = 1 then isnull(lead(_time) over(partition by v_id order by _time), getdate() /*_time*/) end as endtime

        from @t
    ) as t
    where inputs = 9
    and in1 = 1
    group by v_id, grpid
) as src
group by v_id;
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. Just one more thing. If there is no endtime for the last section (no row for the 0) how do I set to todays date as a endtime? Currently in this case last section is not adding up.

Comment: ..@HNP...answer has been edited...GETDATE() might lead to some weird results and even overflow, especially when last in1=1 date was in the past..

Comment: I think you are right. In that case how can we take the date of last record we found for the  group?

Comment: is this correct ? case when lead(in1, 1, 0) over(partition by fleetid order by locationtime) = 0 and inputs = 9 and in1 = 1 then (lead(locationtime) over(partition by fleetid order by locationtime)) else (lead(locationtime) over(partition by fleetid order by locationtime)) end as endtime